# How to use canReuse and routerOnReuse in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have checked this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/OnReuse-interface.html) But it's not very clear to me how to use this.

Requirement is simple I will change param in URL but don't won't to send API request again and again, which I am sending from OnInit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to it. If the route is changed and the routed component is reused because `routerCanReuse()` returned `true`, then `routerOnReuse()` is called by the router, for you to be able to do some initialization on route parameter change.

This seems not yet to be supported in the new RC.1 router.

Comment: do I need to upgrade angular 2, to use this ? Because I unable to see OnReuse in angular2/core or angular2/router ?

Comment: In beta `OnReuse` and `CanReuse` are definitely available. In Angular2 RC.1 it's currently only avilable in `@angular/router-deprecated`.